# Timestamp on email is 5 minutes behind the system time for sender and recipients

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010

Windows 7 (64-bit)
Outlook 2010 (32-bit)

I have a user with Outlook/Office 2010 who sends emails and the time/date is several minutes behind their local system time.

Example:  user1@example.com sends a message to user2@example.com and user3@example.com  All of them have the same local system time (which is accurate).  The time on the clock in user1's system is 1:00 PM but when the recipients receive the message, the Date Sent field is 12:55 PM (effectively 5 minutes BEFORE the message was sent).

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: Does this problem exist if the user emails himself?

Comment: Doesn't Outlook take the date from the `Received:` header *added by mail server*?